# Displaying A Chart Label For Line Chart w/ One Line in Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, charts, plotly

I'm trying to display a line chart with one line, and I'd like for that chart to display a label / legend for that line the same way it would if there were multiple lines.

Here's a quick example:

**CHART WITH LABELS**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

dates = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', periods=100)
random = np.random.RandomState(0)
random2 = np.random.RandomState(1)

data1  = random.random(100)
data2  = random2.random(100)

a_values = ['A' for i in range(100)]
b_values = ['B' for i in range(100)]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  'data': data1,
  'value': a_values
}, index=dates)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  'data': data2,
  'value': b_values
}, index=dates)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df[df.value == 'A']['data'], name='Label 1'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df[df.value == 'B']['data'], name='Label 2'))
fig.show()
```

This will yield the following chart:

[image: Chart With Labels]

My issue is that I'd like the same types of labels to appear in the legend even if there's one line.

If I re-create the same chart but with only one line I'll get the following:

**CHART WITHOUT LABELS**

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df[df.value == 'A']['data'], name='Label 1'))
fig.show()
```

This yields the following graph:
[image: Chart Without Labels]

What can I do to get the value 'Label 1' to appear on the legend on the right hand side?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly: How to customize legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56871095/plotly-how-to-customize-legend)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df[df.value == 'A']['data'], name='Label 1'))
fig.update_layout(showlegend=True)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Have tried that and it did not work for me.  I'll add it to the question to clarify.

Comment: yes, it worked for me, I updated my post. is this what you want?